# causing problem in formatting php file using phpfmt "php -v" returns non-zero code

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here][1]I'm using phpfmt formatter for formatting my php code. when i try to format this code then below error shows
phpfmt: "php -v" returns non-zero code

I have no idea why this is showing and how to fix this .

when i try to format the document using alt+shift+f then it's showing this error.

here is the image link
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7g7J.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: php -v" returns non-zero code means your code has syntax errors

Comment: The extension you are using seemingly requires to have `php` command available in PATH and it isn't the case, not at least in the PATH that the extension can see. If nothing else, it seems you can set the path at `phpfmt.php_bin`. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kokororin.vscode-phpfmt

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed this issue after a week of spacing out. In my case, due to an (unfortunately unsuccessful) attempt to enable Xdebug for some migrations I was testing.

`php -v` simply checks your PHP version information, probably a validation step, which in our case(s), failed.

Open the terminal and type `php -v`.

In my case, the issue came up on the very first line:

```
$ php -v
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
PHP 8.2.6 (cli) (built: May 12 2023 06:23:43) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

And the solution was to go to and delete `/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` and then run `service apache2 restart`.

Your issue might be different, but hopefully it points you/others in the right direction.